# Show that if $F$ is a field, $f(x) \in F[x]$, then $f(x) * F[x]$ is an ideal in $F[x]$, and every ideal of $F[x]$ is of this form.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, ideals

Show that if $F$ is a field, $f(x) \in F[x]$, then $f(x) \cdot F[x]$ is an ideal in $F[x]$, and every ideal of $F[x]$ is of this form.

I'm not sure how to start proving that. If anyone could give me a hint it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It is spelled out in the duplicate.

Comment: I added a dupe link with a more general and more conceptual proof.